# How to trigger an event after AngularJS model has been bound to view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, binding

When I assign a new value to the model of AngularJS I notice there is a little delay before the page gets refreshed with the data of the new model. This happens especially if the model is a very fat one.

I am thinking of showing a mask div while AngularJS is applying the new model to view. Is there a way to do this ?

Basically I would like to get notified when AngularJS finishes applying the new model to the HTML view.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are doing that work inside of a controller, one option would be using the `ng-show` directive on your masking element like:

```
<div ng-controller="someCtrl">
    <div ng-show="loading">I'm a mask</div>
</div>
```

And in your app:

```
myApp.controller('someCtrl',function($scope,$timeout){
    function doHeavyLoading(){
        // do the loading here
        $scope.loading = false;
    }
    $scope.loading = true;
    $timeout(doHeavyLoading, 0)
});
```

This could be done inside a directive's controller as well.

**Edit:** As @MarkRajcok pointed out, there would be no render in between `$loading = true` and `$loading = false` due to javascript's single-threaded nature.  I've added a `$timeout` to postpone the execution of the heavy loading and give the mask a chance to render.

**Fiddle:** <kbd>[Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/kzfJp/)</kbd> Make sure to press 'Run' after the fiddle loads, it won't work on first load because the fiddle waits for all windows to complete.

Comment: Since JavaScript is essentially single-threaded, Angular will not update the view between the `$scope.loading = true;` and `$scope.loading = false;` lines, so I don't think this will work.

Comment: @MarkRajcok Oh, good point. Maybe this could be achieved with some use of $timeout, i'll have to rethink it.

Comment: Yes. I would like to do that inside a controller. I will try out. Thanks

Comment: But just to clarify, it's not HeavyLoading. It should be HeavyBinding. I am trying to bind a very heavy entity to the angularjs view. I suspect the delay is caused by the binding rather than the loading of this entity because I can make sure that the mask displays itself at the moment after the loading and before the binding. But previously I had no control after the loading complete. I would like to have my hand on the binding process of the entity.